# python apscheduler not consistent when there are too many jobs running

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using a scheduler using python apscheduler.scheduler, and In my project, there are too many jobs running, but the machine load wasn't too high, After go through the documentation, I came to the solution that, I have to increase the size of the thread , But I don't know, How to increase the thread
My syntex:

```
scheduler.add_interval_job(triggerTask, interval_time, args=[], misfire_grace_time = None)

scheduler.add_cron_job(triggerTask, interval_time, args=[], misfire_grace_time = None)
```

Comment: Please make your question more explicit. How many tasks do you want to run? How many threads do you use? How much time does one task need?

Comment: @Sraw Number of Task: 90
Number of Thread: Default
One task Time: 3-5 sec

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have 90 tasks to run, you may need to increase the number of threads and if they are calculation sensitive, you should also use `ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(90),   # max threads: 90
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(20)  # max processes 20
}
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(executors=executors)
```

`scheduler` will use `default` executor default, and you can specify executor by `scheduler.add_interval_job(triggerTask, interval_time, executor="<executor's name>")`.

Comment: Thank you @Sraw , As I am new in python, Can you tell me one more thing. Right Now My Syntex is like

from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

scheduler = Scheduler()
scheduler.start()

scheduler.add_interval_job()

. Do I need to replace "from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler" with "from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler" ?

Comment: I'm not sure about it as there is no `apscheduler.scheduler.Scheduler` inside my package. Perhaps you are using an old version, try to upgrade your package and following the latest documentation: http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html

Comment: Thank you @Sraw, I have added 
job_default ={ 'coalesce': False,'max_instances': 3}

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults)

I will check it on my production server and let you know, if I need any further help. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you @Sraw for sharing this.